# PHP prevent strip_tags from removing broken tags

Tags: php, html, strip-tags

I have the same situation as this [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297154/php-strip-tags-removing-everything).

Basically `strip_tags` removes tags including broken tags (the term used in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php#refsect1-function.strip-tags-notes)). Is there another way of doing this that doesn't involve removing `<` and any text after it if it's not an HTML tag?

I'm currently doing this:

```
$description = "&lt;p&gt;I am currently &lt;30 years old.&lt;/p&gt;";
$body = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($description, ENT_QUOTES, "UTF-8"), "<strong><em><u>");
echo $body;
```

But the code above will break something like:

```
<p>I am currently <30 years old.</p>
```

Into:

```
I am currently
```

#### eval.in

Here's an [eval.in](https://eval.in/595272) so you guys could see what I mean.

Comment: garbage in, garbage out. fix the `<` into `&lgt;` first before running it through the various tools.

Comment: @MarcB I've thought of that but look at my example. If I do that then my text would become `&lt;p&gt;I am currently &lt; 30 years old.&lt;/p&gt;` in which case doing `strip_tags` afterwards wouldn't do anything.

Comment: only if you encode EVERYTHING. you can't expect a tool to be smart enough to realize what's broken and what's not. It's up to you to feed in an appropriate input. If you can't fix the input, the you can't use the standard tools. e.g. use a string operation to do `str_replace(' < ', ' &lt; ', $str)` so any "bare" brace is encoded.

Comment: I tried your above with $description = '<p>I am currently < 30 years old.</p>'.. It is returning  - I am currently < 30 years old. Your code is working fine for me.

Comment: @DBA and @MarcB Sorry about my example. It should be `<30` (no space in between). https://eval.in/595272

Comment: Why do you even want to strip the tags? Just escape them correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The HTML you have as input is invalid. So that needs fixing. You could replace all those unclosed `<` by `&lt;` first, and then do your `html_entity_decode` *after* `strip_tags`:

```
$description = "<p>I am currently <30 years old.</p>";
$description = preg_replace("/<([^>]*?(?=<|$))/", "&lt;$1", $description);
$body = html_entity_decode(strip_tags($description, "<strong><em><u>"),
                           ENT_NOQUOTES, "UTF-8");
echo $body;
```

See it on [paiza.io](https://paiza.io/projects/qeTeHhR_Ldbi3pj2wKfD1w)

Alternatively you could use a DOM parser, which in some cases could give better results, but you'll still need to apply the fix first:

```
$description = "<p>I am currently <30 years old.</p>";
$description = preg_replace("/<([^>]*?(?=<|$))/", "&lt;$1", $description);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($description);
$body = $doc->documentElement->textContent;
echo $body;
```

See it on [paiza.io](https://paiza.io/projects/nqaC58I_gsMF7_bV0Bcf3g?language=php)

Comment: this preg replace may only replace the first occurence, see my answer below

Comment: @luky, thanks. Updated, also fixing broken links (8 years later).

Answer (score 1):

Usually when using the less than and greater than operators, you're nearly always going to be using numbers (especially likely here, since you've since said there are no spaces involved). Assuming this is your case, you could quite easily use `preg_match` to regex this case scenario before running it through `strip_tags`:

```
$description = "<p>I am currently <30 years old.</p>";
$description = preg_replace("/<([0-9]+)/", "&lt;$1", $description);
$body = strip_tags($description, "<strong><em><u>");
echo $body;
```

Answer (score 0):

the preg replace made by @trincot works but it may work only for the first occurence like in this example:

```
$v = 'a < b < c';
$v = preg_replace("/<([^>]*(<|$))/", "&lt;$1", $v);
echo $v; // a &lt; b < c
```

so it must be probably in the cycle like this:

```
$v = 'a < b < c';
while (preg_match("/<([^>]*(<|$))/", $v)) $v = preg_replace("/<([^>]*(<|$))/", "&lt;$1", $v);
echo $v; // a &lt; b &lt; c
```